# Rigify: Problems generating rig

Tags: rigging, rigify

[image]

I am having problems with the authoritative addon "rigify". When I push the generate button, it does not generate a IK or anything else. I get it in the panel in the right corner, but cant see the rig. I have Auto Run Python Ticked and haven't done anything to the rig, other than positioning it to the mesh. I dont get any errors either. Anyone know what the problem may be?

Comment: Could you please provide both the blender version and rigify version?

Comment: Blender v.2.78 and Rigify is v.0.4

Comment: try running the setup file again. it might fix something missing. Or untick rigify in addons and retick again. as i remember one of these worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Found the problem... I had increased the size of the mesh and skeleton. Therefore, I did not see the generated rig as it was hidden in the butt of the mesh. Stupid or me, to not notice this earlier...

Thx for answering me batFINGER. Appreciate it :)

Comment: lol ... scale is so often an issue.  Rule of thumb apply scale so its (1, 1, 1) if having object scale isn't needed.  Noticed my version of blender 2.79.1 has v 0.5 of rigify.